# What are "blocks" used for in C++ when we have functions and lambdas?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I found this strange construct that apparently comes  from C and is adopted into Objective-C  and C++ (as an extension). There's even [new development for it in clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html). I was really surprised when I saw this and I've never seen anyone use this.

According to the specs, it seems like you can declare "blocks" with the syntax:

```
// Declaration
int (^x)(char);
void (^z)(void);
int (^(*y))(char) = &x;

// Invocation
x('a');
(*y)('a');
(true ? x : *y)('a')
```

All variables within a block is const-casted. Why is this useful?

> A Block that referenced these variables would import the variables as const variations.

I couldn't even find Blocks in the C++ standard (on cppreference). Does anyone have any links or historical background on why these exist and what they're used for?

NOTE: It has been made adequately clear to me that this is a C++ extension, which probably clang has support for. My question still stands - why do we need this?

Comment: This has never been legal C++.

Comment: hmm... then why is there a section called "C++ extensions"? Maybe it's legal after passing some flag that enables this feature?

Comment: *I couldn't even find Blocks in the C++ standard (on cppreference)* -- Well that should indicate something, like it isn't really C++?

Comment: When you say "block" you mean inline-if? Also afaik in C and C++ the symbol `^` is for XOR operations and nothing else, I have no idea what the hell is even that and it certainly doesn't compile in any compliant compiler.

Comment: It is a language extension.  Non-standard.

Comment: @OneRaynyDay There is no extensions section in the C++ standard.  All there is, is *A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they
do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs
that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this document. Having done so, however, they can
compile and execute such programs.*

Comment: Looks like [tag:objective-c-blocks]

Comment: Well, great, another extension that new programmers will unknowingly use, and then post questions here as if it's real C++.  Just like VLA's.

Comment: So according to Eljay, this is a language extension so clang may be able to compile this successfully with some flags that I'm not aware of (I don't know if this is true). For reference, I'm actually contributing to clang, and I saw casting expression types TO and FROM block types. I've worked with C++ for a long time and I've never seen this either, and assumed it was some backwards compatible C feature at first

Comment: (The intersection of Objective-C and C++ ... is Objective-C even a standard?  I know Objective-C++ is a bit of a mash-up.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, In fairness, it's been 12 years since this was introduced according to the linked page and it hasn't been happening. I don't know what "new development" there is given that the dates end at 2009.

Comment: Actually, given said date, lambdas weren't even part of C++ yet. They still aren't part of C.

Comment: This is Objective-C (or Objective-C++) -- this is how you do lambda's in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Objective-C (or Objective-C++) for a [block](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) and is equivalent to lambda's in C++. For example, the block

```
int (^sqr)(int) = ^(int x) {return x*x};
```

might look like this in C++:

```
auto sqr = [](int x) {return x*x;}
```

clang support both Objective-C and Objective-C++.